# Remove Item By key Using with Own attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, product-collection, delete

I am using the Function `$collection->removeItemByKey($key);`

As i know that the above function remove product one by one based on the **key** and that key is product id,

My Question is Can we remove the product using other attribute instead of product id.

I have custom attribute called product_creator_id, Can I use this custom Attribute to remove the product from collection as removeItemByKey works.

```
foreach ($collection->getItems() as $key => $_product) {
       //product
       //$collection->removeItemByKey($key);
       echo $key;
       print_r($_product->getName());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
foreach ($collection as $key => $product) {
      if ($productStoreId != $currentStoreId) {
           $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
      }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what my answer is. Why don't you just filter for the store ID in the collection right away?

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is possible, but not as efficient as removing it by ID. The `removeItemByKey` method uses an unset on the array, so has constant time.
To remove a custom item by your attribute, you will need to do a loop:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
   if ($product->getProductCreatorId() == 'YOUR_VALUE') {
       $collection->removeItemByKey($product->getId());
   }
}
```

Another option is to filter it out already when you query the database:

```
$valuesYouDoNotWant = array(1,2,3);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_creator_id', array('nin' => $valuesYouDoNotWant));
```

where nin stands for not in array

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = $collection->getItemsByColumnValue('columnname', 'value')
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $collecton->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

        if (!empty($collection)) {
            foreach ($collection as $k => $product) {
                $prdIdd = $product->getEntityId();
                
                //Your Custom Attribute
                $customAttribute = $product->getYourCustomAttribute();
//                if(your condition){
                $collection->removeItemByKey($k);
//            }
            }
        } else {
            return $collection;
        }
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.